# Pentaho Server not started properly ones deployed and restart

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have deployed Pentaho biserver-ce and data-integration (6.1.0.1.196) successfully. It first time loading without any issue.

After I have deployed report set, that is already working on locally. This deploy done using pentaho API. After completing the deployment I can see following issue. Please advise me.

```
16:34:40,983 ERROR [FileHandler] Couldn't find or create CDE /widgets/sample.cdfde  file
org.pentaho.platform.api.repository2.unified.UnifiedRepositoryAccessDeniedException: access denied while updating file with id "5117ec88-9572-43f2-9774-1a69a09c2b0e"

Reference number: 69b57b5c-c978-4292-bcb9-c1967ee04654
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.exception.AccessDeniedExceptionConverter.convertException(AccessDeniedExceptionConverter.java:31)
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.ExceptionLoggingDecorator.callLogThrow(ExceptionLoggingDecorator.java:506)
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.ExceptionLoggingDecorator.updateFile(ExceptionLoggingDecorator.java:433)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.repository.pentaho.unified.UnifiedRepositoryAccess.saveFile(UnifiedRepositoryAccess.java:182)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.repository.pentaho.unified.UnifiedRepositoryAccess.saveFile(UnifiedRepositoryAccess.java:163)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler$1.call(FileHandler.java:114)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler$1.call(FileHandler.java:110)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.security.SecurityHelper.runAsSystem(SecurityHelper.java:396)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.extapi.FileHandler.createBasicFileIfNotExists(FileHandler.java:110)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine.saveAndClose(CdeEngine.java:135)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeEngine.ensureBasicDirs(CdeEngine.java:118)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.CdeLifeCycleListener.ready(CdeLifeCycleListener.java:39)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.PentahoSystemReadyListener.contextInitialized(PentahoSystemReadyListener.java:52)
```

To start pentaho server, taking time and show the following error message as well.

```
16:03:48,064 INFO  [PeriodicStatusLogger] Caution, the system is initializing. Do not shut down or restart the system at this time.
16:04:18,064 INFO  [PeriodicStatusLogger] Caution, the system is initializing. Do not shut down or restart the system at this time.
16:04:29,865 ERROR [BlueprintContainerImpl] Unable to start blueprint container for bundle pdi-dataservice-server-plugin due to unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=org.pentaho.metaverse.api.ILineageClient)]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I have found issue for above scenario. In same server already start some other services called jmx_exporter. Ones it stop and restart again pentaho, pentaho will start without any issue. So I have stop  jmx_exporter and restart pentaho server. Ones start pentaho server then we can start jmx_exporter without any issue. Need to further check why fist scenario not working, due to port or some shared resource using or not